# Android - Keystores, In-App purchasing, and outsourced development

Tags: android, google-play, signature, keystore

I am currently having an Android application developed by an outside third party.  We are at the point where we are ready to implement/test In-App purchasing, but in order to proceed with that we must upload the application to the market first (so we can make the In-App Purchase ID's).  In order to upload to the Market, you must sign the application with a non-debug key.

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to go about this and maintain the privacy of my keystore?
2. Can the keystore be changed later without affecting functionality of the app?
3. What is a good back-and-forth process that would make this work, assuming I will not be coding the In-App purchasing myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keypair used for signing must remain unchanged, otherwise you can't update existing application in Market. Consequently right approach is that the developer gives you an unsigned APK and you sign it locally, then submit to Market.

As Bruno Oliveira suggested in another answer, for debug purposes you can create an application and sign it with the key shared between you and developer. But in this case be ready to create and submit a brand new application for release for the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: So in theory I could generate a signed APK now, upload it, have development continue, then generate another signed APK with same signature and replace the old APK on the market, without causing problems?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the best way to test the app is to have the vendor upload it to Market under a different package name and using a certificate that you and this vendor share. This would be the debug version of the app, which would not be advertised.

After testing and debugging are complete and you're ready to release the production version, you'd have your vendor deliver you the unsigned APK to you with the final package name, and you would upload it to Android Market using your certificate, which you never share with the vendor.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The issue I see with this is that for In-App purchasing your "Public Key" from your Android publisher account must be used for the in-app purchasing.  If a seperate vendor account is created, it would have a different Public Key.